# 'GCLOUD_SDK_PATH' Error

Tags: python

I have run into the following problem

```
Error: failed to find 'gcloud' binary; set option or environment variable 'GCLOUD_SDK_PATH'
```

when executing this line of R code:

```
avfiles_ls( recursive = FALSE,
            namespace = avworkspace_namespace('bdcat-cohort3-stanislawski'),
            name = avworkspace_name('SOLGeneticTopMed')
)
```

This works when I run it in a notebook in a cloud environment but not when I am running an R script inside a wdl on Terra.

Is there a way to more fully quality where the namespace is?

Thanks.
Liz

Comment: Are you running Terra on GCP?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are running Terra on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

It is weird, because Terra is supposed to run on GCP - that is what its intended purpose - and finding gcloud is automatic, you don't need to configure it.

Three suggestions:

1. If the cloud is GCP it is appears to could be a bug with the Broad Institutes platform and should be reported directly on their website. They will know immediately, so if they don't respond immediately its a user problem. This is because they will prioritise system bugs, but user errors they may not respond to.
2. At a guess the error suggests you just need to point to gcloud within .bashrc or .profile, but you don't need to do this on GCP because gcloud is its modus operandi*.
3. Run WDL directly outside Terra.

*The simplest approach is to install miniconda and use it to install gcloud-sdk package and then install Terra from within conda. Assuming Terra is present on "-c bioconda". At this point Terra is forced to see gcloud*.

However, it feels like Terra is being installed on a cloud outside GCP and hence the error.

- To those who don't know GCP gcloud = google cloud.

Comment: Thank you!  Also, the Terra help desk gave me a few lines to add to my docker to do a setup.  Meanwhile, I have found a different way to run my wdl and Rscript so pursuing that for a few days.  Thanks so much for the advice.

Comment: Good it helps. Importantly good to know the Broad Institute actively support Terra. Upvotes would be welcome.